# iBooks on iPad does not remove books I not longer need from iCloud library just puts them back to iCloud

Tags: ipad

I have various books on my iPad that I do not want. Tried to select and delete permanently,it removed from iPad but not from iCloud. I sync'd my iPad to my Mac thinking I could do it that way, but it still doesn't work. How do I delete PERMANENTLY from iPad and iCloud? Are some books put there by Apple so they can't be removed?

Comment: Are these books that you've purchased from the iBooks store?

Comment: No, I downloaded from Bookbub